# When my camera changes orientation, my app crashes for no reason

Tags: java, android, crash, camera, orientation

ok so maybe there is a reason. i'm still new to this. here's my code. inside of the on finish method. im getting an error on this line: `camera.setParameters(p);` when i turn the camera or the phone. thats the line that causes the error. if i comment it out. the camera may stay on. and then i get an error on the `camera.stopPreview();` line.

```
public void strobeTimer182() {
superStrobe = new CountDownTimer(857, 10) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textView2.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished
                / 2);

        if (millisUntilFinished % 5 == 0
                || millisUntilFinished % 2 == 0
                || millisUntilFinished % 3 == 0
                || millisUntilFinished % 7 == 0) {

            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(p);
            camera.startPreview();

        } else {

            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(p);
            camera.stopPreview();
            textView2.setText("off");
        }

    }

    public void onFinish() {
        textView2.setText("done!");
        // Set the flashmode to off
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        // Pass the parameter ti camera object
        camera.setParameters(p);
        //camera.stopPreview();
        textView2.setText("off");

    }
}.start();
superStrobe.onFinish();
```

}

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: @CommonsWare i have a logcat application on my phone. it gives me a line with an error on it. and thats what i go look at, im not sure what a java stack trace is.

Comment: "i have a logcat application on my phone" -- depending on your phone's OS level, that may not work. Use development tools, like your IDE's access to DDMS, to view LogCat. "im not sure what a java stack trace is" -- this is covered in any serious book on Java development, plus countless Web sites.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity.Hope it helps :)

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Comment: this could be helpful but, if i were showing interstitials onResume();  a locked screen orientation would mean i would loose money when the user turns the phone. and with the type of app ive created, they may want to use the phone in any orientation.

Comment: i think it has something to do with the state of the camera not switching over to the onResume(); lifecycle majiggy,

Comment: It would not lock the screen orientation,it just avoids orientation change issue,i would just to try it just once.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void strobeTimer182() {
    superStrobe = new CountDownTimer(857, 1) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            if (millisUntilFinished % 2 == 0) {

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();

            } else {

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();

            }
            if (millisUntilFinished == 0) {

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();

            }

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // causes errors
        }
    }.start();
    superStrobe.onFinish();
}
```

or

```
        public void strobeTimer182() {
    superStrobe = new CountDownTimer(857, 1) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {



                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();


        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // causes errors
        }
    }.start();
    superStrobe.onFinish();
}
```

the first option is if you wanted to cycle through more than three states, and then set it back to the first state.

The second worked for the on off effect of the strobe but i chose the first.